# MySQL flexible conversion to numeric data

Tags: mysql, function, type-conversion, numeric, categorical-data

I have a `MySQL` database which has several categorical columns. In searching the database, having a conversion of categorical data and data in multiple columns to one numeric variable I could use for sorting would be nice.

Ideally this conversion would be a function and not just another data table since the mapping itself may change. It could probably be as simple the following code, but I’m not sure what the best way to do something like this in `SQL` would be. Thanks in advance.

```
a = 0 
if b==“val1” {
    a += 1 
} 
if c==2 {    a += 2 } 
if c==1 {    a += 1 } 
return a
```

Where a is the numeric column and `b` and `c` are values I’m mapping to `a`. Same example in table form with everything joined if these columns are in different tables.

```
+---+------+------+
| a | b    | c    |
+---+------+------+
| 0 |    3 | xxxx |
| 1 |    1 | xxxx |
| 2 |    2 | xxxx |
| 1 |    3 | val1 |
| 3 |    2 | val1 |
| 2 |    1 | val1 |
+---+------+------+
```

Comment: Your question is not clear and that equation you included bears little resemblance to anything I've ever seen in a relational database.  Can you include some table data which explains your question?

Comment: Sure. I'll put together a db version if it will help. That's essentially what I want to do in a high level language though and with columns as variables, regardless of where they are in the db.